# How to remove subview added in other TableView cell when tap on one cell, in Custom swipe (instead of swipe to delete) Cell (swipe to mail/sms)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my **iPhone UITable view** application

**I need to add Two Buttons when user swipes on table view Cell / Row.**

One for **Compose mail button** one for **Send sms button** to the contacts.

*I implemented following code to add Send Mail **(Blue Cloud Button**) only for now*

```
//Add a left swipe gesture recognizer in view Did load
      UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                                       action:@selector(swipeRow:)];

      [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
      [contactsTable addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
      [recognizer release];    





- (void)swipeRow:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
      //Get location of the swipe
      CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:contactsTable];
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [contactsTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
       UITableViewCell *cell = [contactsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


       UIButton *MailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                  [MailButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sendData.png"]         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                MailButton.frame=CGRectMake(150, 0, 40.0, 30.0);
         [MailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(SendMail)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


      //Add mail button if index path is valid
      if(indexPath)
      {

            [cell addSubview:MailButton];

      }

}
```

*It execute fine and add button to the selected cell/row when we swipe on the cell.*

**`But when we swipe another cell the buttons on the previous cell are does not hide / removed` repeated as follows**

**I want to not showing (remove) buttons on the other cells while taping swipe on the other cell Only one cloud button At a time ..**

Answer (score 1):

Why not you can keep the button in XIb and add it to respective cell? It is a single object for the entire class, so there will be no duplicate of buttons in previous cells. Please try.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is one ivar for storing the lastIndexPath where you added the cloud button.
And on every time to add new button you have to remove the button from the perviously added indexPath and assign the new indexPath to the ivar.

Your code may be look like this (not tested).

in .h file on property like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath;
```

and in .m file synthesize it.

Now the code will be look like this

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                                       action:@selector(swipeRow:)];

      [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
      [contactsTable addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
      [recognizer release];    





- (void)swipeRow:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
      //Get location of the swipe
      CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:contactsTable];
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [contactsTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
      //New Code 
      UITableViewCell *cell = [contactsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      if(lastIndexPath != nil)
           UITableViewCell *last = [contactsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath];
      //End 
       UIButton *MailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                  [MailButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sendData.png"]         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                MailButton.frame=CGRectMake(150, 0, 40.0, 30.0);
         [MailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(SendMail)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
MailButton.tag = 1111;// New code

      //Add mail button if index path is valid
      if(indexPath)
      {
            //New Code
            UIButton *mb = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:1111];
            [mb removeFromSuperview];
            //End 
            [cell addSubview:MailButton];
            lastIndexPath = indexPath;// New Code
      }

}
```